# Awesomium WebControl Hang

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, web-controls, awesomium

I have a tabcontrol and in the tabcontrol I have two tabitems, and both of them contain an awesomium Webcontrol. However after some random time the Webcontrols don't display anything.  When I try to call a method on them I get an InvalidOperationExcepion which tells me: "This IWebView instance is invalid. It has either been destroyed or it was never properly instantiated."

Why is that? Am I Missing some extra configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuned out it was an Awesomium bug, it was fixed.